# Add file mime type in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT with script

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, powershell, windows-registry

I have a few Win8 VMs that don't include `.xlsx` in [`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAzRy.png), so it's not recognized by the OS, and to add it manually for each VM would be inconvenient.

Is it possible to add such type via a shell script?

Comment: The easiest way would be to export HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xlsx from the machine where it's working to a reg file and apply this reg file to all other Vms centrally (via GPO or any other deployment way). Take a note that this registry key is created upon Office installation. So you'd better re-istall or repair office to have it in place.

Comment: It can be manually added via `reg add` or by doing what @Hardoman mentioned, exporting the key and importing the resultant `.reg` via `reg import`